# How to change TargetExt through visual studio UI

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, csproj

I'm building a console based app. By default it's output extension is .exe. I want to change it to .com. Presently I'm able to do it by adding `<TargetExt>.com</TargetExt>` in .csproj. But I'd like to know how to do this via Visual studio 2010 UI.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't natively changeable in the UI. Your best option, other than what you have done, is to add a postbuild command that renames the file, but if the csproj change is working, there is probably no reason to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is going to be complex for me. Is it possible to give a prebuild command like - If OutputType is console, then rename to .com?

Answer (score -1):

I was looking at examples that showed you could `echo $(TargetExt)` in the Post-build event. So, I wondered if you could `set TargetExt=.com` in the Pre-build event. As it turns out, you can.

Comment: Tested with Visual Studio 2022, not working